# How to get result from mysql that contains in variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I'm not getting the result I need and I'm sure it is a small problem here. 
I have a column(mfg_req) in my database which have a record with **10M**.

My variable in php does have the text **10M40SABCDE**.
What I want is to search in my table and get the results **starting** with this variable.

My MYSQL query does look like below but no results:

```
SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE mfg_req LIKE '10M40SABCDE%'
```

I also tried the below query but no results

```
SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE mfg_req LIKE '%10M40SABCDE%'
```

Also tried the below but it shows me all records except the one I need with **10M**

```
SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE '10M40SABCDE' LIKE CONCAT('%',mfg_req)
```

I have tried to put the % behind mfg_req but then it will show me all records including the one I need.

I cannot figure it out how to get the result I need. If someone can help me with my query I would appreciate it a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: use: SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE mfg_req LIKE '10M40SABCDE%'; to find rows where mfg_req starting with 10M40SABCDE

Comment: tried that already but it's giving no results.

Comment: Can you post table structure & some sample data from table?

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question

Comment: It work in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b52c1/1

Comment: your first query should work provided you have data in table starting with '10M40SABCDE'

Answer (score 0):

Let's say:

```
$var = '10M40SABCDE';
```

...then your SQL statement must be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM specific_req WHERE mfg_req LIKE '{$var}%'";
```

It would be best if you show a snippet of your code, too.

Comment: Here an sql example on how the table looks like which is giving 0 results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/271ed1/2

Comment: ok, from your example, it will surely return an empty set. why? because the wildcard `%` means match any character that follows the previous string. if your going to use `'10M40SABCDE%'` as your criteria, that will only yield to results like `10M40SABCDE_123`, `10M40SABCDEdefghij`, `10m40sABcdE`, and so on. in your example in JSFiddle, if you want the query to return a recordset you would rather do `SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE col LIKE '10m40%'`. i hope you get the idea now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do get the idea, but because the record in my database will have value 10M40, and my variable 10M40SABCDE, it will not give me the result I want. Somehow I do need to have the query like SELECT * FROM T WHERE COL ....starts with? '10M40' but I cannot get the query right.

Comment: i think i follow what you mean now. let me think about it... sorry, my bad

Comment: does the SQL statement from my previous response won't resolve your issue? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '10m40%'`

Comment: With that SQL query it will give me only that record. But I want to get the record that contains that value in the variable. So for example. $var = 'ABCDEFG'. In table value = ABC. Exactly as the query in the sqlfiddle.